# Obtener los ultimos 5 registros ordenados en BD

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Hola tengo intencion de sacar los últimos 5 registros en base de datos por orden de menor a mayor pero los 5 ultimos

```
SELECT * FROM document_treballador_pieles_semanal WHERE tr_id_treballador=10 AND mes_semana_anio=08 ORDER BY tr_piel_id ASC LIMIT 5
```

Lo que me saca

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero que saque

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has probado así:

```
SELECT * FROM document_treballador_pieles_semanal WHERE tr_id_treballador=10 AND mes_semana_anio=08 ORDER BY tr_piel_id DESC LIMIT 5
```

Así te ordenará de mayor a menor.

**EDIT:**

He hecho una prueba rápida, creo que es esto:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Cosa ORDER BY id DESC) c WHERE ... ORDER BY id ASC
```

Sin el where me muestra esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos

Comment: Si asi me lo ordena de mayor a menor, pero yo quiero de menor a mayor los 5 últimos

Comment: Perdona, leí mal.

Comment: Esto me sale #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '5 * @Kaz

Comment: Se me ocurre que sea el where dentro de los (..)

Comment: lo probaste en mysql phpmyadmin?

Comment: Lo que creo que no funciona es el TOP 5

Comment: No, lo probé en el SQL Management